# how to read csv file and the printing the data after some manupulations?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am facing problem while reading the csv file in python  while printing  only the header/column names are printed again and again and data is not printed.

The output  contains only the column names. The rows values are not printed. please help me with the problem.

**My code is below.**

```
import csv
import sys
import datetime
import math
import re

f=open('VehicleMaster.csv','r')
try:
    reader=csv.DictReader(f,delimiter=',')
    num=' '
    regx= re.compile('[,-/]')
    for row in reader:
        dt1=row['Date_Registered']
        for xd in dt1.splitlines():
            d,m,y=regx.split(xd)
            dt2=('/'.join((d.zfill(2),m,'20'+y.zfill(2) if len(y)==2 else y)))
            row['Date_Registered']=dt2
            dt3= str(datetime.datetime.strptime(dt2,'%d/%b/%Y').date())
            #print(dt3)
            row['Date_Registered']=dt3![enter image description here][1]
            #print(row)
            print(num, '\t'.join(row))
            if num == ' ':
                    num=0
            num=num+1
```

**Output:-**

```
Workstream_from_AL  Manager work_steam  risk_score  Base    Count   Total_Downtime_Hours    Class   Vehicle_Description C111111 Total_Maint_Costs   Date_Registered smr Workstream  Latest_Mileage  Base_Location   Major_Repair_   Average_Downtime_Hours  Age_in_Months__17_Mar_15_   Status  Ob_Board_Power_ No_of_SMR_Jobs  Reg_Number  down_time   Cost_Centre mileage Workshop    age Date_of_Reading
1 Workstream_from_AL    Manager work_steam  risk_score  Base    Count   Total_Downtime_Hours    Class   Vehicle_Description C111111 Total_Maint_Costs   Date_Registered smr Workstream  Latest_Mileage  Base_Location   Major_Repair_   Average_Downtime_Hours  Age_in_Months__17_Mar_15_   Status  Ob_Board_Power_ No_of_SMR_Jobs  Reg_Number  down_time   Cost_Centre mileage Workshop    age Date_of_Reading
2 Workstream_from_AL    Manager work_steam  risk_score  Base    Count   Total_Downtime_Hours    Class   Vehicle_Description C111111 Total_Maint_Costs   Date_Registered smr Workstream  Latest_Mileage  Base_Location   Major_Repair_   Average_Downtime_Hours  Age_in_Months__17_Mar_15_   Status  Ob_Board_Power_ No_of_SMR_Jobs  Reg_Number  down_time   Cost_Centre mileage Workshop    age Date_of_Reading
3 Workstream_from_AL    Manager work_steam  risk_score  Base    Count   Total_Downtime_Hours    Class   Vehicle_Description C111111 Total_Maint_Costs   Date_Registered smr Workstream  Latest_Mileage  Base_Location   Major_Repair_   Average_Downtime_Hours  Age_in_Months__17_Mar_15_   Status  Ob_Board_Power_ No_of_SMR_Jobs  Reg_Number  down_time   Cost_Centre mileage Workshop    age Date_of_Reading
```

**Input:-**
Count   Reg_Number  Status  Vehicle_Description Date_Registered Age_in_Months__17_Mar_15_   Latest_Mileage  Date_of_Reading No_of_SMR_Jobs  Total_Downtime_Hours    Average_Downtime_Hours  Total_Maint_Costs   Major_Repair_   Manager Cost_Centre Ob_Board_Power_ Class   Workshop    Base_Location   C111111 age mileage smr down_time   work_steam  risk_score  Workstream  Workstream_from_AL  Base

1   PN57KTE Current - On Road   LEYLAND DAF LF45 160 Day 6.0 Der    20-May-08   81.92876712 195591  2-Feb-15    30  110.83  3.694333333 14269.36    Major crane repairs £5,093.45 job no V79166 GORDON THOMPSON 40001072    NO  HGV North East Truck & Van Ltd  Tees - Repair 1                             0   Repair  Tees

1   YP09LFX Current - On Road   FORD TRANSIT 350 2.4 TDi Der/Man    10-Jun-09   69.23835616 62589   9-Mar-15    10  169.5   16.95   6166.99 New engine & injectors £4,287.57 job no V81240  BARRY WATSON    40001032    YES LCV Kestrel Truck Services Limited  North Tyne - Repair 1       0.961643836 1.11E-05    3.548325662 3.941860465 1   9.451841074 Repair  Repair  North Tyne
1   YP09KZK Current - On Road   FORD TRANSIT 350 2.4 TDi Der/Man    24-Jun-09   68.77808219 77171   12-Jan-15   12  40.25   3.354166667 5867.05 New engine £5,499.87 job no V78692  BARRY WATSON    40001032    YES LCV Howdon  North Tyne - Repair 1       0.955251142 1.11E-05    3.375747986 0.78003876  1   6.111048999 Repair  Repair  North Tyne

1   YP09LCL Current - On Road   FORD TRANSIT 350 2.4 TDi Der/Man    1-Jul-09    68.54794521 68703   19-Jan-15   10  101.25  10.125  8521.22 New engine £6,450.14 job no V85143  JOHN RICHARDSON 40001053    YES LCV S Jennings Ltd  Wear - Repair 1     0.952054795 1.11E-05    4.902888377 2.354651163 1   9.209605446 Repair  Repair  Wear

Comment: could you provide the input file sample

Comment: plz make your code more readable in this post

Comment: in input data the first is the column names and then the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's happen because you use `csv.DictReader` — in iteration over its items your `row` variable will be instance of `dict` type.
While you iterating over `dict`(in `join` method of string), you are iterating over its keys, which is the names of rows, while you want to iterate over its values.

So, you should replace `print(num, '\t'.join(row))` with `print(num, '\t'.join(row.values()))`.

*Note:* standard python dictionaries are unordered. I don't remember if `csv` module use `OrderedDict` or any similar.

Comment: Kammala can u help me some more things like after this I need to generate the sequence of month from the lowest date to September 2021. Say for example my date column contains date like 2009-05-02,2008-11-24,2009-09-23.. and so on.. and I have to generate  each year and each month till the mentioned date. please help me in this case.

Comment: I can't fully understand what do you want, but I suggest you to learn more about [generators in python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Also there is awesome package [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which makes it possible to generate list of dates with desirable difference(e.g. every month)

Comment: ok will check  with that. I was telling like if I have column of date type and the dates  from year 2008 to 2015 contains only few month from each year. So I want to add those missing months from each year in order. How can I achieve that?

Comment: This is another question, so you should ask it separately. By the way, if you try to read links above, you will know enough to generate range of dates by yourself.